# Is it possible to utilize a list as a single column value in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have such dictionary:

```
d = {'name': 'John',
     'part': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from such records, for example:

```
+----+---------------------+
|name|         part        |
+----+---------------------+
|John| ['A', 'B', 'C']     |
+----+---------------------+
|Bill| ['F', 'B', 'H']     |
+----+---------------------+
|Jack| ['R', 'N', 'L']     |
+----+---------------------+
```

I need to be able to select rows, based on the content of `part` list. Something like:

```
df.part.isin(['B', 'A'])
```

And it should give me John and Bill rows. Is it possible?

**UPD** Sorry for dumb question, but how to make a single cell value from a list? If I try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it gives:

```
   name  part
0  John    A
1  John    B
2  John    C
```

Comment: You can check edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert `lists` to `set`s and test membership with `&`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['part'].apply(set) & set(['A','B'])]
print (df)
   name       part
0  John  [A, B, C]
1  Bill  [F, B, H]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['part'].apply(set) & set(['A','B']))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: part, dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'name': 'John',
     'part': ['A', 'B', 'C']}

df = pd.Series(d).to_frame().T
print (df)
   name       part
0  John  [A, B, C]
```

Comment: Is it possible to have them in ordered way or at least take length of intersection, if in df we have 3 entries: `1: {'A', 'B', 'C'}, 2: {'A', 'F', 'G'} and 3: {'X','Y', 'Z'}` so `df['part'] & {'A', 'B'}` will give 1st and 2nd entry with some data on length of intersection, something like `1 - {'A', 'B'}, 2 - {'A'}` or `1 - 2, 2 - 1`

Comment: Do you think `df['lens'] = df['part'].apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(['A','B'])).str.len()` or `df['lens'] = df['part'].str.len() - df['part'].apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(['A','B'])).str.len()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
In [161]: df
Out[161]:
   name       part
0  John  [A, B, C]
1  Bill  [F, B, H]

In [162]: df.part.apply(lambda c: set(['B','C']) & set(c)).str.len() > 0
Out[162]:
0    True
1    True
Name: part, dtype: bool

In [163]: df.part.apply(lambda c: set(['X','Y']) & set(c)).str.len() > 0
Out[163]:
0    False
1    False
Name: part, dtype: bool
```